# JQuery using DateTimePicker addon dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need DateTimePicker on my site, I try [this example](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

and not working. My code [is here](http://pastebin.com/XEUUrtBj)

js file is **also included** in my folder in localhost (/var/www). Thanks...

Comment: why dont you try with some proper documentation :) http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ It's as easy as: including the jquery ui js file, then with one line of code you initialise the datepicker. The more shiny stuff you want on it, the more "complex" it gets, but the basic it's litterally one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were missing jquery and jquery ui. [See the working code](http://jsbin.com/igogob/1/edit#html,live) at
http://jsbin.com/igogob/1/edit#html,live